# Hot is to heat as cold is to

Tags: nouns, adjectives

Can you please fill in the blank?

Hot is to heat as cold is to....

In other words, what is the noun for "cold"?

Comment: _Cold_. Zero-derivation. It's pretty frequent in English.

Comment: Cold is not a noun. There is no such "thing" as cold - only heat. Things which have heat added to them are "hot" - things which have heat taken away from them are "cold".

Comment: @jeb Maybe scientifically, but it can definitely be used as a noun. "I can feel the cold", "don't let the cold in" etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ***cold***. That is, the noun has the same form as the adjective.

Comment: So the same way I can say `"I burnt some wood to generate heat."` I can say `"I set up the AC to generate some cold"`? It just sounds weird

Comment: You could say that, or you could use *coolness*. Your "weird" sentence is grammatically correct. However if that's the sentence you had in mind with your question then you should have stated it there.

Comment: It wasn't specifically that sentence. I'm just trying to pick your brain more

Comment: Heat is definable physically; the noun is arguably abstract, but somewhere near the concrete end of the spectrum. Cold is, I would argue, nearer the abstract end - it is not physically definable. The adjectives hot and cold refer to temperatures of masses, not directly to their heat contents.

Comment: The *heat* in Death Valley is too much for me. The *cold* in Antarctica is too much for me.

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks - that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you were looking for a verb, then I suggest chill

You can heat something and you can chill something

You cannot cold something

I personally prefer chill to cool in this situation - in my opinion cold is to the verb cool as hot is to the verb warm.

- *He heated the object until it was red hot*
- *He chilled the object until it was ice cold*

as opposed to

- *He warmed the object until it was room temperature*
- *He cooled the object until he could touch it*

Comment: Yes good point! I was looking for the noun specifically, but there's a verb missing in our vocabulary too....

Comment: or *cool* works too.

Comment: See my changes.

Answer (score 0):

To cool is the verb that you want. Hot is to heat as cold is to cool. And there is an answer from a really chilled out cool dude.

Comment: Yeah, see my additions to my answer